# call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, pdo, syntax-error

So, I'm pretty sure that my query should be fine. But I did a var_dump and it does return false, so I'm not sure why though. Could someone tell me what is wrong with my query or whatnot, and how to fix it? I'm pretty sure it's not my custom function db_connect, it's worked before. What could be the problem?

here's my code:

```
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
session_start();

$dbh = connect_db('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project1', 'jharvard', 'crimson');

if (!isset($_POST['quantity'])) { //go back if incomplete
    redirect('search');
}   

if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    redirect('index');
}
elseif (!isset($_SESSION['row'])) {
    redirect('stocks');
}

$amount = htmlspecialchars($_POST['quantity']);
$value = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['row']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['email']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['q']);   

if (!filter_var($amount, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || $amount < 0) {
    redirect('search');
}

$dbh->beginTransaction();
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE email = $email"); //get balance 
$result1 = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = $email"); //get id

var_dump($result);

$bal = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$id = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//if ($bal < $amount * $value) {
//  redirect ('search');
//} 

$bal = $bal - $amount * $value; //subtracting from total

$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO stocks (name, shares, id) VALUES ('$name', '$amount', '$id')");
$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: "my query should be fine" "var_dump ... return[s] false" Does not compute.

Comment: I got boolean false. What do you mean "does not compute"

Comment: If you get false, then *your query isn't fine*.

Comment: I know. What is wrong with the query then?

Comment: Did you try asking your database tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the $email variable inside quotes:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE email = '$email'"); //get balance 
$result1 = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Or concatenate:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'");
$result1 = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'");
```

Comment: Your first solution should work. But, I don't think your second solution will work because you didn't put quotes over there